# How to remove default body text of mail composer sheet in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposer

How to remove text saying "Sent from my iPhone" in mail composer sheet.
I have tried by sending empty body but no luck.
Please give some clue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change boilerplate "Sent from my iPhone" text in MFMailViewController message body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477241/how-to-change-boilerplate-sent-from-my-iphone-text-in-mfmailviewcontroller-mes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your device settings --> Mail, Contacts, Calendars --> Signature .There you can see it. Empty the signature.