# MFMailComposeViewController attachment file

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I attach files to a message using an MFMailComposeViewController, the data is attached before the signature, This signature connected with separate file .txt. 
Is it possible to display the attachments AFTER the signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sending image data or image file (it is not clear from your description)change it according to the type of file you are sending
in the button action 
    `UIImage *imageName =[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_sml.png"];
    IMgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageName);`

and in the displayComposerSheet method add this

```
[picker addAttachmentData:IMgdata
                 mimeType:@"image/png"
                 fileName:@"content-id"];
```

Comment: Let me explain what is problem. I am sending a pdf file as an attachment by mail. At the receiver end he will get two file first one is pdf and other one is ATT00001.txt file(which only contain text "Sent from my iphone") .  I want to remove this .txt file.How can I do this.

Comment: that we need to do in the phone settings i think reffer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477241/how-to-change-boilerplate-sent-from-my-iphone-text-in-mfmailviewcontroller-mes

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am still searching How can I remove ATT00001.txt file?